# How to get the kind of import in a Webpack loader?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm writing my own Webpack loader and I would like to know if there's any way I could get the kind of import out of the following:

```
import 'module' // load the entire module
import dflt from 'module' // default import
import { foo, bar } from 'module' // named import
```

My guess is that it's somehow possible to retrieve it from `this` context of the function, but there's hardly any documentation I could find on the Internet, except some vague descriptions like [this one](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html).

```
module.exports = function (source) {

  // import type?

  this.cacheable()
  return source
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Good question! If it's all the same to you, you could make a babel plugin, instead of a webpack loader. https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash for an example. I just don't know what your use case is.

Comment: @StefanDragnev, I've got both local & global CSS files in my project. Depending on the kind of import, I want the `modules` option in the `css-loader` to be either true or false. My loader is supposed to be a simple wrapper around the `css-loader`.

Right now, I'm using callbacks to test against the path instead of regular expressions to determine if it's a local or a global CSS file. It would be nice to simplify it, so I could just use `/\.css$/` for the `test` property & then use my loader to handle it.